# Как удалить товар с корзины без перезагрузки?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть кнопка для удаления

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger lii" name="del" data-id="<?=$value->id;?>">удалить</button>
```

удаляется при помощи очистки сессии

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]);
```

}
и обновляло страницу используя ajax

```
$('.lii').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/cart',
        data:{id:$(this).data('id')},
        success:function(){
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Как сделать удаление без перезагрузки страницы ?

Comment: Очевидно - вам нужно с помощью js привести страничку к виду, в который она приходит после перезагрузки - поудалять товар из DOM и из js. Какой вы ответ хотите услышать?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.lii').on('click',function(e){ // <-- Помещаем событие в переменную e
    var $button = $(e.targert);
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- Прерываем событие по-умолчанию
    $.ajax({
        url:'/cart',
        data:{id:$(this).data('id')},
        success:function(){
            //location.reload(); <-- Убрать перезагрузку страницы и сделать обновление узлов DOM которые содержали инфу о товаре
            $button.closest(".product").remove();
        }
    });
    return false; // <-- Возвращаем false
});
```

Comment: В `success:function(){ }` Мне нужно сделать вывод массива $data ? в котором лежит товар или как ? я не как не разберусь с ajax

Comment: @Andrii ну с удалением всё просто. Если товар в данный момент отражён на странице просто найдите его контейнер и удалите. Этого должно хватить по идее. Например, у вас есть кнопка `.lii`, а лежит она в контейнере с классом `.product`. После успешного удаление в success ajax ищете родителя кнопки и удаляете его: `$('.lii').closest('.product').remove();` Обновил пример кода в ответе, думаю понятно будет.

Comment: удаляет. теперь нужно мне в success:function вывести товары да ? после remove. Правильная логика ?

Comment: @Andrii не знаю что там у вас по логике дальше, это уже к вопросу не относится. :)

Comment: Как сделать обновление узлов DOM которые содержали инфу о товаре ?